# FirebaseInstanceId service class creates ANR after installing from android studio

Tags: android, firebase, authentication

[image]

I am facing issue while installing app from android studio.Basically the issue is regarding firebase as i have given my logcat details below.After Installing app the android shows ANR and not allows to run the app.

```
Timeout executing service: ServiceRecord{eeb00db u0 
 onemobile.dhl.com.onemobile/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService}
09-02 12:57:39.862 1190-1232/? W/ActivityManager: Timeout executing service:   
ServiceRecord{eeb00db u0 
onemobile.dhl.com.onemobile/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing exactly same issue, and my app configuration was also exactly similar as yours.

The issue was caused by the latest Facebook SDK I was using in my code, it crashes the Firebase before the app start hence the app goes to ANR.

I set my Facebook SDK version as 4.35.0 and that solved the issue.

Try it out and let me know if it was helpful.